# Crystal Reports - Get list of group members

Tags: crystal-reports, report, group

I have a classic report, with groupped and summaryzed datas. In the footer of the report, I have to write down which subgroups belong to which group. It should appear as it appears in the report designer's preview panel (group section):

[image]

Based on the image above, this is what I would need: "Group 01: 911010, 911011, 911012"

Can you recommend a formula that can be used to solve this?
Since it has to be in the footer of the report, I think I have to write a separate formula for each group.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a simple report like this
[Grouped report details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLZSP.png), I suggest to create one formula field per grouping level; for illustration purposes, I added a third formula to the details section.
[Report editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLJZo.png)
I used following formulas

```vb
// _Collector_group1

WhilePrintingRecords;

Global StringVar Array arrGroupLabel;
Global StringVar Array arrStringValue;
Global StringVar Array arrNumericValue;

Global NumberVar i;

i := i + 1;

Redim Preserve arrGroupLabel[i];
Redim Preserve arrStringValue[i];
Redim Preserve arrNumericValue[i];

arrGroupLabel[i]    := ToText({Tabelle1_.F1},"0000");
arrStringValue[i]   := "";
arrNumericValue[i]  := "";

""
```

and

```vb
// _Collector_group2

WhilePrintingRecords;

Global StringVar Array arrGroupLabel;
Global StringVar Array arrStringValue;
Global StringVar Array arrNumericValue;

Global NumberVar i;

i := i + 1;

Redim Preserve arrGroupLabel[i];
Redim Preserve arrStringValue[i];
Redim Preserve arrNumericValue[i];

arrGroupLabel[i]    := "";
arrStringValue[i]   := {Tabelle1_.A};
arrNumericValue[i]  := "";

""
```

and

```vb
// _Collector_details

WhilePrintingRecords;

Global StringVar Array arrGroupLabel;
Global StringVar Array arrStringValue;
Global StringVar Array arrNumericValue;

Global NumberVar i;

i := i + 1;

Redim Preserve arrGroupLabel[i];
Redim Preserve arrStringValue[i];
Redim Preserve arrNumericValue[i];

arrGroupLabel[i]    := "";
arrStringValue[i]   := ""; 
arrNumericValue[i]  := ToText({Tabelle1_.B},"#,##0.00");

""
```

Finally, I suggest placing per array one additional formula field side-by-side into the Report Footer for print-out. Important to format all these output fields as "can grow"

```vb
//PrintoutGroupLabel

WhilePrintingRecords;

Global StringVar Array arrGroupLabel;
Global StringVar Array arrStringValue;
Global StringVar Array arrNumericValue;

Join(arrGroupLabel, Chr(10))
```

and

```vb
//PrintoutGroupStringvalue

WhilePrintingRecords;

Global StringVar Array arrGroupLabel;
Global StringVar Array arrStringValue;
Global StringVar Array arrNumericValue;

Join(arrStringValue, Chr(10))
```

and

```vb
//PrintoutGroupNumericValue

WhilePrintingRecords;

Global StringVar Array arrGroupLabel;
Global StringVar Array arrStringValue;
Global StringVar Array arrNumericValue;

Join(arrNumericValue, Chr(10))
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XlsJ.png)

For me, output in Report Footer looks like this. As you don't want to print-out details, just skip the PrintoutGroupNumericValue field.

Comment: This is something like what I want, but I need to list the subgroups as groups, textually, independently of each other. For example:

Contents of group 01: 911010, 911020, 911030

Contents of group 02: 854100, 832500

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to simply insert a **CrossTab** in the report footer.
Make the row fields be the Group Level 1 column and the subgroup column.
Use a summary of your choice (e.g. some count or sum of interest).
You can suppress certain aspects of the crossTab (e.g. grid lines) if desired.

An even simpler alternative is to insert a **subreport** containing the same 2 group levels but showing only the Group labels.